# Command prompt having trouble finding python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, command-prompt

I'm using python 3.8.1 and now been coding for a bit with PyCharm and wanted to download PyGames and the problem that I'm facing is that with command prompt "pip" command I get error: No Python at 'C:...\PYTHON\python.exe'

Comment: Are you trying this at a terminal window within PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short explanation:

in `Pycharm` you need first to configure your python path in order to both run your code and both for use any python command (i.e. pip which is actually `python.exe -m pip <your command>` ).

Seem like you configured it under `'C:...\PYTHON\python.exe'`

You need to change it  in the following way: 
Go to `File | Settings | Project: <your_project_name> | Project Interpreter`

and there:

in setting icon pick "add" -> and add your python env.

Comment: Great, if it works I appreciate if you will accept the answer (: